# cancancan: accessible_by vs can

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cancancan

I have a test that is failing with `accessible_by` but passing with `can?`.

In the following example, there are two `@things`. These lines are being used in the same test.

```
assert_equal true, (@admin_ability.can? :manage, @things[0])     # Passes
assert_equal true, (@admin_ability.can? :manage, @things[1])     # Passes
assert_equal 2, @things.count                                    # Passes

assert_equal 2, @things.accessible_by(@admin_ability, :manage).count
# Returns 0 instead of 2 => Fails
```

Is there a difference in how these terms work that might account for the disparity?

Comment: what does this yield? ----> assert_equal 1, @things[0].accessible_by(@admin_ability, :manage).count and also ---->  assert_equal 1, @things[1].accessible_by(@admin_ability, :manage).count  ----> maybe that will help you think of the solution?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon That leads to an error: `undefined method 'accessible_by' for #<Company:...>`

Comment: hmmm of course, i think it is because you are calling it on an object rather than the class. try calling it on the class and using pluck(:id) to get the specific object you are after?

Comment: sorry you'd use select to get the object